# CGRect is ZERO for animated sprites

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

This is what appears to be a big failure of SpriteKit.

I have a bunch of animated sprites that have their own class like this:

```
- (id)init {

  self = [super init];

  if (self) {

    NSMutableArray *images=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:14];
    for (int i=1; i<=14; i++) {
      NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"boat%d.png",i];
      SKTexture *tempTexture=[atlas textureNamed:fileName];
      [images addObject:tempTexture];
    }

    NSUInteger numberOfFrames = [images count];

    SKAction *animate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:images timePerFrame:1.0f/numberOfFrames resize:YES restore:NO];
    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:animate];
    [self runAction:forever];


  }

  return self;
}
```

All classes are subclasses of SKSpriteNode class.

At some point I want to get the sprite frame, height or whatever, then I do

```
MySprite *sprite = [[MySprite alloc] init];

CGRect frame = sprite.frame;  // frame returned is (0,0,0,0)

// or you may think
CGRect frame2 = [sprite calculateAccumulatedFrame]; // frame returned is (0,0,0,0)

// or you may also suggest
CGSize size = sprite.texture.size; // result is (0,0)
```

Or in other words, there is no way to get the frame or dimensions of that sprite.

So, unless I create code when the sprite initializes to read the size of one image and store that on a property, I am screwed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You could try setting the first texture from the array as the sprite's texture before animating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MySprite *sprite = [[MySprite] init];
```

Also, you forgot to add alloc method call.

You frame is (0,0,0,0) 'cause you are not setting current texture for your current sprite during initialization process, so its 0,0,0,0.

Comment: The first part of the question has the code that initializes the sprite. The sprites appear animated on the screen. The alloc was missing on the question. The original code has the alloc. I am not setting a texture because it is using an animated texture.

Comment: now I see I have to set the texture and then the animated sequence but when Apple shows how to create an animated sprite they don't mention that, thanks to their crappy documentation, as usual. Thanks.

Comment: You can't blame the Apple docs for not mentioning something that is self-understood (a sprite node without a texture has no frame).

Comment: I can because a SKSpriteNode that has no texture should not appear or be rendered in the first place and by the way, it appears even if you create a SKNode. You attach an animation to a SKNode and it appears perfectly and also the calculateAccumulatedFrame should calculate the accumulated frame because if this animation is showing on a node, it is filling a frame that is not being calculated.